# Script to add a channel on murmur with ice

Tags: voip, ice

I installed the ice library for python on my Centos 7 server and I would like to develop a script for dynamically creating murmur channel with a given name.
Is there some documentation for Ice somewhere, or a ready made script to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Ice to create a script for adding and removing channels.